# Failed to instantiate the default view controller after switching from .xcodeproj to .xcworkspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

When I create a brand new project in Xcode and choose Storyboard for the interface, I can run the app on my phone just fine.

However, when I do `pod install` (the only deps I added are `pod 'Plaid'`) and then switch over to the .xcworkspace file, I get this error:

```
[WindowScene] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
```

I have tried the usual fixes (check Is Initial View Controller etc.)

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must assign entry point to your project, go to your sceneDelegate file and set it like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.backgroundColor = .white // or the color that you prefer
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let controller = ViewController() // or the first controller presented in your app
    window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error, except the background colour is now white.